# Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref

Tags: xml, perl, hash

```
if(ref($newconfig->{'supervisor'}) ne 'ARRAY' && $newconfig->{'supervisor'} eq undef){
       warn "empty set of supers.";
       remove_supervisors($self, $id);
}
```

`$newconfig` is imported `XML` using `XMLin` from the `XML:Simple` library (I know its horrible & i should be using one of the others but its not my decision).
The XML typically is structured like so:

```
<queue>
   <supervisor></supervisor>
   <supervisor></supervisor>
</queue>
```

what i'm trying to achieve with the code included above is to execute the `remove_supervisors()` function when no supervisor stanzas are found. So an XML import of,

```
<queue>
</queue>
```

Every time i try & reference the hash to check, the script fail with the error

> Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref

I've also trued `if(!exists $newconfig->{'supervisor'})` which results in the same error.

**How do i check if the associative index of the object exists?**

Comment: Always check parsing result => `my $newconfig = XMLin(..) or die "Can't parse xml";`

Comment: @Сухой27 would you suggest this is a parsing issue as opposed to a code issue?

Comment: You wouldn't have code issue in case you've checked parsing result.

Comment: When working with XML::Simple or similar, I use something like

    `sub force_list { !defined($_[0]) ? () : ref($_[0]) eq 'ARRAY' ? @{ $_[0] } : $_[0] }`

Then, you can do

    `my @supervisors = force_list($newconfig->{supervisors})
       or ...;`

Comment: I am glad that you have `use strict;` in your code ( or `use v5.12;`, or something that enables strict mode for you ), this is an excellent example of why it is a good idea even in a production environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two significant issues here. The first is that your test is fundamentally wrong, and the second is that you are probably trying to process malformed XML

#### The Test

Your condition

```
ref($newconfig->{'supervisor'}) ne 'ARRAY' && $newconfig->{'supervisor'} eq undef
```

is wrong in all sorts of ways

- You're trying to check whether the hash element is defined by comparing it to `undef` as if it was a string. You can't do that; you have to use `defined` instead of `eq` or `==`
- You have a `&&` in there which should be an `||`
- You must test for definedness *first* before any other checks make sense

If I were you I'd start by extracting the `supervisor` value from the hash before going any further. It makes your code more concise and simple to read

```
my $super = $newconfig->{'supervisor'};
```

You're trying to make sure that the `supervisor` element is *defined* and is an array reference. So if you were testing for *validity* instead of *invalidity*, and bearing in mind that you must test for definedness *first* as calling `ref $supervisor` will raise a warning if `$supervisor` isn't defined, you'd have

```
if ( defined $super and ref $super eq 'ARRAY' ) { ... }
```

So you want to negate that condition, and for me the simplest way would be just to use `unless` instead of `if`

```
unless ( defined $super and ref $super eq 'ARRAY' ) { ... }
```

But I realise that some people are uncomfortable with `unless`, and remembering that `not ( A and B)` is the same as `not(A) or not(B)` you could write this

```
if ( not defined $super or ref($super) ne 'ARRAY' ) { ... }
```

#### The value of `$newconfig`

You show hardly any of your code, but I think it's safe to assume that

```
Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref
```

refers to `$newconfig` being undefined, because you're not using anything else as a hash reference in any of the code that you show

That means `XMLin` is probably returning a null string `""`, and you should investigate why that could be

Answer (score 1):

An empty element is parsed by [XML::Simple](http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple) as a reference to an empty hash.

```
    if ('ARRAY' ne ref $newconfig->{supervisor}
        || ! grep 'HASH' ne ref || keys %$_, @{ $newconfig->{supervisor} }
    ) {
```

Also, `$var eq undef` is wrong. Use [defined](http://p3rl.org/defined) instead.